# Which Apache configuration needed for Network-NAT Intranet access?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, nat

There's the situation :

Intranet hosted here with `intranet_name.domain.com` with a private network address `172.x.x.x`.

I have to give access to this intranet to an another site. They add a DNS entry corresponding to `remote_intranet.other_site_domain.com` `10.x.x.x`.

In my firewall I do a NAT of `10.x.x.x`to `172.x.x.x`.

Because of the NATing I presume that my configuration will continue to listen to the `172.x.x.x` address.

Does I have to put a new `ServerName remote_intranet.other_site_domain.com` on my intranet VirtualHost ?

I read about `Proxy` too.

I don't know Apache very much. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a line to your virtualhost:

```
ServerAlias remote_intranet.other_site_domain.com
```

and yes, leave the ip and port alone.